# ValidationAPI java swing

Tags: java, swing, validation

im working on project swing application and i want to validate jTextFields which i have in my GUI.
I found ValidationAPI.jar which i added into my project, but there is really bad documentation for it.
I have an error in group.validateAll(); call and i dont know how to fix it. 
Does anyone use this API? and know how to fix it.

```
final SwingValidationGroup group =  SwingValidationGroup.create();
group.add(generationsTextField, StringValidators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
StringValidators.NO_WHITESPACE,
StringValidators.REQUIRE_VALID_INTEGER);


generationsTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    checkValidation();
}
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    checkValidation();
}
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    checkValidation();
}
private void checkValidation() {
    Problem validateAll = group.validateAll();
    if (validateAll.isFatal()) {
        startAlgorithm.setEnabled(false);
        isValid = !validateAll.isFatal();
    } else {
        startAlgorithm.setEnabled(true);
        isValid = !validateAll.isFatal();
    }
 }
});
```

when i call `validateAll();`

it gives me an error below  --

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openide/util/Lookup at
>   org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.swing.SwingComponentDecorationFactory.getDefault(‌​SwingComponentDecorationFactory.java:154)
>   at
>   org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.swing.SwingValidationGroup.(SwingValidation‌​Group.java:82)
>   at
>   org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.swing.SwingValidationGroup.create(SwingValidation‌​Group.java:87)
>   at com.mendelu.ga_scp.gui.GUI.(GUI.java:43)

.

Comment: Could you please post the entire error? Cannot find symbol ...?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openide/util/Lookup
 at org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.swing.SwingComponentDecorationFactory.getDefault(SwingComponentDecorationFactory.java:154)
 at org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.swing.SwingValidationGroup.<init>(SwingValidationGroup.java:82)
 at org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.swing.SwingValidationGroup.create(SwingValidationGroup.java:87)
 at com.mendelu.ga_scp.gui.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:43)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you created a plain Java application project in Netbeans. For validation you took the ValidationAPI.jar without any further apis. ValidationAPI.jar is part of the `Netbeans Application Framework` (NAF), a quite complex set of libraries to write standard "desktop" applications. The ValidationAPI depends on other packages (jars) from the NAF. And you miss at least the org.openide.util.Lookup class.

You may solve the dependencies manually (put into your project all jars or with maven) or create a NAF programm from scratch.

Another option is to use a framework agnostic validation library such as [OVal](http://oval.sourceforge.net/).